# How to export products using command line

Tags: magento2, export, cli, command-line

How to export products along with all attributes & images/video using command line?

Comment: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-run-product-import-in-magento-2-from-cli.html

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang I cudnt find info on exporting products via cli on the blog link. It was about Extension.

Comment: OHH!! my mistake it was import not export. Apologies.!

Comment: @PadhiyarGaurang even for import,..it is about Extension.. not CLI

Comment: You need to create your own command and write logic for export :)

Comment: @Pawan oh, I thought there would be inbuilt command via bin/magento

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to run an export job in Magento 2 via CLI:

```
php -f bin/magento export:job:COMMAND JOB_ID
export:job:run
```

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites: The Add Secret Key to URLs option is set to Yes. The option is configured in the Commerce Admin under Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security.

In the Admin, navigate to System > Data Transfer > Export.

**Select**

Entity Type: Products
Export File Format: CSV
Field Enclosure: leave unchecked.
Click Continue.

The following message is displayed: "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon".

Expected result

The .csv file with the exported products is displayed in the grid in a couple of minutes.

Actual result

The .csv file with the exported products is not displayed in the grid in 10 minutes or more.

Cause
A known issue with the Export functionality in the Adobe Commerce application part version 2.3.2.

Solution
There are two possible solutions for the issue:

Disable the Add Secret Key to URL option.
Run the

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

**For Cpanel**

```
 php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

command manually, and optionally configure it to be run by cron.
See details for both options in the following paragraphs.